# Polymer best practise for script in index.html

Tags: polymer

What is the best practice for linking a script to the `index.html` in polymer. I have a menu on in my index file and what to use `dom-if` to hide certain buttons depending on the users permission. That permission check uses `ajax(iron-ajax)`. I am unsure how to link Polymer(`{}`), to the index, as the index is not a custom element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="app">
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{myProp}}">
  </template>
</template>

<script>
  var app = document.querySelector('#app');
  app.myProp = true;
</script>
```